# Windows XP guest virtual machine: (vhd) Gives no display in Normal mode, Ok in safe mode

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, vhd

I'm trying to use my old Windows XP system on Ubuntu 15.10 Host. After having copied the hard drive to a vhd file, I'm trying to boot it:

1) in Normal mode:
the windows XP login appears normally for a while, 
then: black screen.

But... I can still hear the "login" sound, the "new hardware detected" sound etc... When I shutdown, I hear again the "logout" sound. So it appears it's only a problem of black display, the system seems to run.

2) In safe mode, everything is working. with the display normal.

```
* Host:
```

Ubuntu 15.04. 64bits. VirtualBox 5.0.0 with extensions pack

```
* Guest:
```

Windows XP 32bits.

1. Display:

   - 64MB Video memory
   - Enabled 2D acceleration (I've tried to disable it)
2. System:

   - Base memory: 1024MB (same as my old winxp sytem)
   - Enabled IO APIC (I've tried to disable it and it doesn't boot)
   - Processor: 2 Cores. Execution cap 100%. Enabled PAE/NX (I've tried to disable it too).
   - Acceleration: Enabled VT-x/AMD-V and Enabled Nested Paging (I've tried to disable it too).

Comment: I haven't done it before but I think the issue is within the realm of  preparing the vhd correctly. I hope somebody can answer, and if they don't then do keep us up to date  re what works

Comment: have you installed the **Guest Additions** inside the guest? - i'm not sure but maybe it helps...

Comment: @DJCrashdummy  That was it! I was following a tutorial from LinuxVoice magazine ( http://www.linuxvoice.com/issues/004/lv4-virtualbox.pdf ) and it wasn't noted to install that (but the tutorial is a bit old maybe). Everything's working now. Put it as an answer and I will validate your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the [**Guest Additions**](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html) are known for *"better performance and usability"* i advise you to start your machine in the safe mode and install it inside the guest.
[image: VirtualBox Guest Additions]

according to the manual the Guest Additions offer:

- Mouse pointer integration
- Shared folders
- **Better video support**
- Seamless windows
- Generic host/guest communication channels
- Time synchronization
- Shared clipboard
- Automated logons (credentials passing)

Comment: **NOTE:** don't forget to upgrade the Guest Additions as well after upgrading VirtualBox.

Comment: Thanks for for all the doc and image! By the way, installing by "devices>Install Guest Additions..." didn't work for me and I simply run the virtual CD from inside windows XP

Comment: well... that's the way it works! - this menu-entry mounts an iso into your virtual drive. if you have deactivated the autorun in your guest, you have to start the installer/autorun yourself.